# Azure Custom Log Alert - Not Firing

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-alerts

I am trying to debug an issue with an Azure Alert not firing. This alert should run every 30 minutes and find any devices that have not emitted a heartbeat in the last 30 minutes up to the hour. In addition, an alert should only be fired once for each device until it becomes healthy again.

The kusto query is:

```
let missedHeartbeatsFrom30MinsAgo = traces
    | where message == “Heartbeat”
    | summarize arg_max(timestamp, *) by tostring(customDimensions.id)
    | project Id = customDimensions_id, LastHeartbeat = timestamp
    | where LastHeartbeat < ago(30m);
let missedHeartbeatsFrom1HourAgo = traces
    | where message == "Heartbeat"
    | summarize arg_max(timestamp, *) by tostring(customDimensions.id)
    | project Id = customDimensions_id, LastHeartbeat = timestamp
    | where LastHeartbeat <= ago(1h);
let unhealthyIds = missedHeartbeatsFrom30MinsAgo 
    | join kind=leftanti missedHeartbeatsFrom1HourAgo on Id;
let deviceDetails = customEvents
    | where name == "Heartbeat"
    | distinct tostring(customDimensions.deviceId), tostring(customDimensions.fullName)
    | project Id = customDimensions_deviceId, FullName = customDimensions_fullName;
unhealthyIds |
join kind=leftouter deviceDetails on Id
| project Id, FullName, LastHeartbeat
| order by FullName asc
```

The rules for this alert are:

[image]

When I pull the plug on a device, wait ~30 minutes, and run the query manually in App Insights, I see the device in the results data set. However, no alert gets generated (nothing shows up in the Alerts history page and no one in the Action Group gets notified). Any help in this matter would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The query gives either one or more than one result it will alert you. Make sure your query result gives at least one row result. confirm if it applies to the logic.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the reply.

If there are any devices that are offline, when I run the query manually, I can see them in the resulting table. However, even after waiting some amount of time, the alert never fires.

Answer (score 0):

I can see your **KQL Query** take several ***times to execute***, and it ***consume more resource*** usage to run the query.
[image]

[Optimize your query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/query-optimization) to avoid more resource utilization and quick response of your query result.

Make sure your *alert processing rule* **Status** should be **Enabled** like below
[image]

Once it is done make sure your query result should be **Greater than or equal to 1**. So that the alert processing rule will check the threshold if it matches the condition the alert will fire.

Still, you get the issue alert not firing try to **delete the alert** and run your query in a **Query Editor** and try to create a **New alert rule**.
[image]